# how to simulate play one piano note in android?

Tags: android, midi

I will simulate a piano key-board in android pad. When use press one key, I would like play some sound, I know JetPlayer can play midi file, but in this case, I have no mid file, just one single note, how to do it?

Comment: You can't specifically "play" a piano on the phone.. You have to have a sound byte, that is used for that particular note.

Comment: By the way, Different piano key will trigger different sound.

Comment: Hi JoxTraex, Thanks your answer. Now, I have mp3 file for every piano note, but it is too large. (100 mp3 file and every mp3 file's size is about 20K). So, I am trying to find a way to play sound without mp3 file. By the way, what the meaning of "sound byte" for particular note --- I am new for midi?

Comment: sound byte means a particular sound. And 20k is not big at all. The only other option you have is generating a frequency tone, but this does not sound like a piano, that is all you can do.

Comment: I still want to know if I can write my code without mp3 file or wav file, just using JetPlayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIDI and using MP3s are completely different things.  You could program MIDI to sound like a piano but you will have to do a lot of work to get a good result and you need to be aware that the result will depend on the sound hardware of the phone.  Android support for MIDI is also very poor and you'll need a lot of code to do the plumbing work.  I recommend that you stick with MP3s.  100x20k files is not really that big.  You could possibly make them smaller with some additional compression.  For things like single notes, you really don't need high quality audio.  Try it out on your phone with 16kbps, 32kbps and 64kpbs.

If you go with MP3, You might want to consider using the SoundPool classes.  Take a look at the tutorial [here](http://www.droidnova.com/creating-sound-effects-in-android-part-1,570.html)

This enables you to create a HashMap with an index for each sound which you can then use to play each individual note.  The index could be the key number for example.  To play a note, you would simply call the playSound method of the SoundPool with the relevant index.

I'm assuming that you have a limited number of piano keys and therefore, the overhead of loading multiple sound files (your MP3s) is acceptable.  If you have a large number, you might need to think about only loading the sound files for keys which are visible to the user in order to keep your memory usage under control.

Comment: Above solution works for me. the total mp3 file is about 2M. It is a little bigger for user downloading the apk file.

Comment: After reading related document, it seems that (JetPlayer)midi is a little complicated for my project. So, I will use mp3 file and SoundPool.

Comment: @DavidGuo can you please share the sound files you have used? is there any source of them in internet or you have created them yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can't specifically "play" a piano on the phone.. You have to have a sound byte, that is used for that particular note.